# How to improve docker low network speed (bridged network)

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, docker

I'm hosting my owncloud instance within a docker container. I'm familiar with the docker technology and possibilities, but the actual "doing" is new to me. At the moment I'm not sure if my host device grants the network access/speed like I intended (docker container uses bridged gigabit interface **br0**).

## Host device information & configuration

My host device is gigabit enabled:

```
tharmar@nuc:~$ dmesg |grep em1 
[    2.249914] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 em1: renamed from eth0 
[    2.262696] systemd-udevd[125]: renamed network interface eth0 to em1 
[    5.290467] device em1 entered promiscuous mode 
[    8.430199] e1000e: em1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None 
[    8.430231] br0: port 1(em1) entered forwarding state 
[    8.430240] br0: port 1(em1) entered forwarding state 
[   17.434250] br0: port 1(em1) entered forwarding state
```

I changed my host /etc/network/interfaces manually to this config:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto em1
#iface em1 inet dhcp
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports em1
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

I adapted the br0 configuration from a tutorial I found online (no link at hand). On my host I reach the following download speed:

- internet = 5,64MB/s
- internal network = 88.0MB/s

## Docker container information

- Image  : l3iggs/owncloud
- Run-Cmd:

> docker run --restart=always -v
>   /media/500GB/owncloud/config:/usr/share/webapps/owncloud/config -v
>   /media/500GB/owncloud/data:/usr/share/webapps/owncloud/data --name oc
>   -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -d l3iggs/owncloud

docker network

```
tharmar@nuc:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
c5444bf94367        bridge              bridge              
544630efd75a        none                null                
ab858df7af57        host                host
```

docker network inspect bridge (I found my container within this network)

```
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "c5444bf94367cf747e0c05dc967587c608ae8401fa1fccf65233fd4334b91a43",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Containers": {
        "665f87dbf4f48d1ee96e71df592923323a91702b7bd0845ca59e0de6d068ce30": {
            "Name": "oc",
            "EndpointID": "7853f7630e4e1f64cd6241e1edb550906240e5acdb5cb158fe6cd5bd926171ab",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I can find the bottleneck? Did I configure something wrong, or not at all?

If you do need more information about my environment please don't hesitate to ask, I'll update the question asap.